# unable to bind static json data to list in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngfor

Am new in Angular framework. Now I create an angular web app using `angular@cli`.

Following are the versions I used:

`Angular CLI: 6.1.3` `Node: 10.15.3` `OS: win32 x64` `Angular: 6.1.2`

Currently I am trying to bind a `JSON` data into list in `HTML` file. But it wont work,checked lot of examples, still its not working
its showing an error:

> "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". I don't know why it's undefined.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" ng-repeat="list in SERVICE_LIST">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <a href="">{{list.name}}</a>
      <span class="active-circle">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Component Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-home',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  SERVICE_LIST = [
    {"id":1, "name": "Service 1", "port": "8090", "ip": "10.0..4", "status": "InActive" },
    { "id":2,"name": "Service 2", "port": "8090", "ip": "10.0..4", "status": "InActive" },
    {"id":3, "name": "Service 3", "port": "8090", "ip": "10.0..4", "status": "InActive" }
  ]
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I spent a lot of time and tried to figure out what I am doing wrong and no idea.

I tried to add `ng-repeat` inside `div,ul and li` tags and other solutions from stack but getting the same error. If am trying to display a single variable value inside the HTML file its work fine. What was the hidden issue in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`ngFor`** with Angular 6, not **`ng-repeat`**:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngFor="let list of SERVICE_LIST">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="">{{list?.name}}</a>
    <span class="active-circle">&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ecample: [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9prc2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: i have tried ng-for instead of ng-irepeat it wont work.

Comment: kindly check the demo

Comment: now its work fine.thank you so much for your immediate replay